# Django not redirecting to desired url after login

Tags: python, django

I am trying to built a online book store and using django registration redux I have built a 2 way verification login system. After user login I want it to redirect to the main home page (/store in my case), but for some reason it's directing to accounts/profiles, I don't know from where is it fetching this url.

Here's my Settings.py code

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '&icg8)16be&h!rw)6_#3#v!1dn5nx_*k1rv7lx@c(88tw5z6$a'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    'store',
    'registration',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'bookstore.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'bookstore.wsgi.application'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
)

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


# Registration

ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN = True
LOGIN_REDIRECT_USER = "/store/"
```

And here's my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'bookstore.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url (r'^store/', include('store.urls'), name='store'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    url ('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace = 'social')),
```

And My login.html

```
<form method = "post" action =".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type = "submit" value="LogIn"/>
    <input type = "hidden" name = "next" value = "{{next}}"/>
</form>

<a href = " {% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}"> Login With Facebook</a>
```

A help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you please share your `views.py`, also?

Comment: Is the error for normal login or login via facebook? Does "/store/" exist? Or is it only a root with no child url as `r"^$"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used the wrong setting name. It should be

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/store/"
```

You have `LOGIN_REDIRECT_USER`.

Comment: *facepalm* I looked at the line 5 times expecting an error there, but just couldn't see it

Comment: Damn!! Thanks a lot !! Typos drained my brain for hours...Thanks a lot :D

Comment: 3+ years later, this was the simple solution i was looking for.